# R: replacing predicted values with indicator values

Tags: r, matrix, replace, machine-learning, subset

I have I have a matrix that's 19 mil predicted observations of `ID` and `Rating`. I want to replace the predicted `Rating` for `ID` that are in the actual `Rating`.

Here is a demonstration of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
train <- data.frame(1:10,c(1,2,NA,4,5,NA,7,8,NA,10))
names(train) <- c("ID", "Rating")
pred <- data.frame(1:10, c(1,1,3,4,2,4,5,6,7,1))
names(pred) <- c("ID", "Rating")
```

I want the final pred to be:

```
pred <- data.frame(1:10, c(1,2,3,4,5,4,7,8,7,10))
names(pred) <- c("ID", "Rating")
```

Any suggestions?

Attempt:

Answer (score 2):

Just subset the data using `[]` brackets and `is.na`.

```
> train$Rating[is.na(train$Rating)] = pred$Rating[is.na(train$Rating)]
> train
   ID Rating
1   1      1
2   2      2
3   3      3
4   4      4
5   5      5
6   6      4
7   7      7
8   8      8
9   9      7
10 10     10
```

Or, going the other way:

```
> pred$Rating[!is.na(train$Rating)] = train$Rating[!is.na(train$Rating)]
> pred
   ID Rating
1   1      1
2   2      2
3   3      3
4   4      4
5   5      5
6   6      4
7   7      7
8   8      8
9   9      7
10 10     10
```

Comment: make sure the ID's are in same order in both though.